# How to get jQuery ajax calls to work from greasemonkey page events

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey, jquery-get

I have a GM script which inserts a link on to the page, and then adds an event listener for when its clicked.

This then runs a function which contains among other things some jQuery.get calls. These calls however do not seem to fire unless I use the unsafeWindow version of jQuery.

```
function runMyFunc() {
    console.log('myFunc is called');

    $.get('index.php',function () {
        console.log('jQuery.get worked');
    });
}

$("#someHook").before('<a id="myLink">Link</a>');

$('#myLink').click(runMyFunc);
```

The above will output 'myFunc is called' to console, but will not do anything with the .get

I'm using FF17 and GM1.5, jQUery from http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js

Is there a nicer way of getting this to work than using unsafeWindow? I had this working before GM 1.0 and have a lot of $.get which I would need to change in my scripts, not all of which are run from the same scenario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine for me.  **Why/How** do you think `$.get` is not working?

Remember that you will never see the `'jQuery.get worked'` message if there is a server error (404 etc.) with `index.php`.  Did you check the Firebug ***Net*** panel, or *Wireshark*, etc. to see if the AJAX call was made?

Anyway, you can see that code working, plus some error handling if you install this Greasemonkey script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _delme9h762
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @include  http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZqhRH/*
// @require  http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

function runMyFunc() {
    console.log('myFunc is called');

    $.get('index.php', function () {
        console.log ('jQuery.get worked');
    } )
    .error ( function (respObj) {
        console.log ("Error! ", respObj.status, respObj.statusText);
    } )
    .complete ( function (respObj) {
        console.log ("AJAX Complete. Status: ", respObj.status);
    } )
    ;
}

$("#someHook").before('<a id="myLink">Link</a>');

$('#myLink').click(runMyFunc);
```

And then **visit [fiddle.jshell.net/ZqhRH/1/show/](http://fiddle.jshell.net/ZqhRH/1/show/)**.

Note, the console will show:

> myFunc is called
>   Error! 404 NOT FOUND
>   AJAX Complete. Status: 404

On the jsFiddle site, because `index.php` does not exist there, but `$.get()` is otherwise working perfectly.

Comment: When I test $.get without using the link event I see the 'jQuery.get  worked' message. The script above fails at jsfiddle (no index.php found)

On the site I am trying to run the code I get:
Error! 

0

TypeError: xhr is undefined
jquery...user.js (line 21)

AJAX Complete. Status: 

0

Comment: bleh, I dont like this comment box, keeps thinking my returns are submits. I see the GET request in firebug only for the non-link scenario tests

Comment: Verify: The answer script did not "fail" at jsFiddle.  It made the requested get (unlike what the question reports), and properly returned a 404 -- merely because the specified page doesn't exist.  The `$.get()` worked as intended.

Comment: As for getting error 0 on your site.  See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1023867/331508), but something (not shown in the question), that your script, and/or the server, and/or the target page are doing is the problem. **Link to the target page** (or at the very least, make a proper SSCE that demonstrates the problem).

Comment: Yeah, looks to be the same thing. I added their error function suggestion:
  if(xmlHttpRequest.readyState == 0 || xmlHttpRequest.status == 0) { console.log('premature ajaxulation'); return;  } // it's not really an error
  else console.log ("Error! ", textStatus, errorThrown);

I also stuck your test page up on my own site and it tested fine when I changed the get target. So the target page (which i dont own) must be up to something dodgy.

Comment: I have since tested on a 'mobile' version of the same site. My code works fine. The normal version has a load a lot of their ajax code - so I assume there is something in their code that interferes with mine.